# Factorial(s) of N numbers in for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, console-application, factorial

I am working on a problem from [CodeChef](https://www.codechef.com/problems/FCTRL2) where I need to calculate the factorial of n numbers.

The user inputs a number which determines how many ints to perform a factorial calculation on and then inputs the numbers to calculate.

My problem is with the multiplication itself. For example if I have an int == 5 then the result will be 20 (it will calculate n by the last factorial only, not by all of them)

Here is where the problem exists:

```
for(int x = 0; x < _numbersToProcess.Length; x++) {// Loop throuigh Array by index
    for (int y = 1; y < _numbersToProcess[x]; y++) {// Y is equal to less than index x
         _result[x] = _numbersToProcess[x] * y;// Multiply x by y then add to array
    }
}
```

The outer loop defines how many calculations to perform.

The inner loop calulates the factorials by iterating through each index of `_numberToProcess` and multiplying it by every number less than the number to be calculated on.

The problem is that the factorial calculation overwrites itself,

for example:

factorial of 5 result: `20` but it should be 120 (it overwrites itself until it reaches the last multiplier)

So I tried the following:

```
_result[x] = _numbersToProcess[x] *= y;
```

This is obviously the same as `_numbersToProcess[x] = _numbersToProcess[x] * y;`

But this gives a completley different result:

If we again input 5 then this will result in the output of -1899959296.

I know I can easily copy and paste from other submissions but I want to know why my method does not result in the correct output.

Here is the method in its entirety:

```
int _numbers = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());// Get number of ints to calculate
        int[] _numbersToProcess = new int[_numbers];// Array of inputs
        int[] _result = new int[_numbers];
        int i = 0;

        while(i < _numbersToProcess.Length) {
            _numbersToProcess[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            i++;
        }

        for(int x = 0; x < _numbersToProcess.Length; x++) {// Loop throuigh Array by index
            for (int y = 1; y < _numbersToProcess[x]; y++) {// Y is equal to less than index x
                _result[x] = _numbersToProcess[x] *= y;// Multiply x by y then add to array
            }
        }

        for (int n = 0; n < _result.Length; n++) {// Y is equal to less than index x
            Console.WriteLine(_result[n]);// Write to console
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Start by solving a simpler problem. **Can you correctly compute the factorial of a single number?** If you can't do that then you cannot compute the factorials of multiple numbers. Delete all this and start over; make a program that does something *simple* and then *test the heck out of it* until you are confident that it is correct. Then once you have a solid base of correct code to work from, **use the correct code as a tool in implementing a solution to the more complex problem.** This is how we build complex programs: by building solid small programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int _numbers = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());// Get number of ints to calculate
    int[] _numbersToProcess = new int[_numbers];// Array of inputs
    int[] _result = new int[_numbers];
    int i = 0;

    while(i < _numbersToProcess.Length) {
        _numbersToProcess[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        i++;
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < _numbersToProcess.Length; x++)
        {// Loop throuigh Array by index
            int fact = 1;
            for (int y = 1; y <= _numbersToProcess[x]; y++)
            {// Y is equal to less than index x
                fact = fact*y;
            }
            _result[x] = fact;
        }


    for (int n = 0; n < _result.Length; n++) {// Y is equal to less than index x
        Console.WriteLine(_result[n]);// Write to console
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
```

Problem is with your inner for loop. here, you are always, overriding result array.

i.e for y=5;
   inner for loop executes for 5 times.

```
iteration -1 : 
  y=1,
  _numbersToProcess[5]=5
  _result[x]=5

  iteration -2 : 
  y=2,
  _numbersToProcess[5]=10
  _result[x]=10

iteration -3 : 
  y=3,
  _numbersToProcess[5]=30
  _result[x]=30

.
.
.
.
.
```

thus it goes for 12 iteration as your _numbertoprocess[5] is changing and stops once it reaches less than 0 i.e -1899959296.

```
iteration 12:
  _numbertoprocess[5] = -1899959296.
```

i.e **you are changing numbertoprocess everytime in your inner for loop.**

you can verify it by adding

```
Console.WriteLine(y);
Console.WriteLine(_numbersToProcess[x]);
Console.WriteLine(_result[x]);
```

in your inner for loop.

Comment: that is working and thankyou but I want to know what I am doing wrong instead of just blindly copying and pasting

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int y = 1; y < _numbersToProcess[x]; y++) {// Y is equal to less than index x
    _result[x] = _numbersToProcess[x] *= y;// Multiply x by y then add to array
}
```

In loop condition `y < _numberToProcess[x];`. It compare between `y` and `_numberToProcess[x]` array value

I think you should edit loop condition to `y < x`

Be lucky.

Answer (score 0):

Here i'm using a recursive function factorial

```
      /* Factorial function*/
            int factorial (int n)
            {
            return (n*factorial(n-1))
            }

          int _numbers = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());// Get number of ints to calculate
                    int[] _numbersToProcess = new int[_numbers];// Array of inputs
                    int[] _result = new int[_numbers];
                    int i = 0;

                    while(i < _numbersToProcess.Length) {
                        _numbersToProcess[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        i++;
                    }

                    for(int x = 0; x < _numbersToProcess.Length; x++) {// Loop throuigh Array by index

                            _result[x] = factorial(_result[x])// Multiply x by y then add to array
                        }
                    }

                    for (int n = 0; n < _result.Length; n++) {// Y is equal to less than index x
                        Console.WriteLine(_result[n]);// Write to console
                    }

                    Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int c, n, fact = 1;

  printf("Enter a number to calculate it's factorial\n");
  scanf("%d", &n);

  for (c = 1; c <= n; c++)
    fact = fact * c;

  printf("Factorial of %d = %d\n", n, fact);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Downvoted because "_I know I could easily copy and paste but I want to know why my method does not result in the correct output_."

Answer (score -2):

Check this out maybe it will help...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long f(int n) {
    if (n==0) return 1;
    else return n * f(n-1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    long *factorials;
    int *inputs;
        int n;

    printf("Enter number n = ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    factorials = (long *) malloc(n*sizeof(long));
    inputs = (int *) malloc(n*sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        long k;
        printf("Enter %d number = ", i + 1);
        scanf("%ld", &k);
        inputs[i] = k;
        factorials[i] = f(k);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("Factorial for %d = %ld\n", inputs[i], factorials[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Downvoted because "_I know I could easily copy and paste but I want to know why my method does not result in the correct output._"